# How to add trailing slash to only page & post URL in database?

Tags: database, wordpress, preg-replace

On wordpress, how can we add a trailing slash to the links that has been used on the page/post contents using database? I need a SQL query to replace URLs to have trailing slash.
I tried to do some query & also tried to use "Find & Replace" on phpmyadmin but it also showed the image URLs which will have issue if we add the trailing slash to image URL.
So, I only need query to run for page/post URL of **wp_posts** table & **post_content** column.

Comment: please share web url or screenshot what you want excetly

Comment: I want to replace links without trailing slash to have slash i.e. update URL www.example.com to www.example.com/ in database.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this only for urls currently stored in the database, or also for any new posts and pages that are published?

Comment: I am using WordPress and now I have changed the permalink so the new posts & pages will have a slash at the end. But I need to update old page URLs which are linked on the page/post contents.